# Multiple focus at a time (textbox and datagridview)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, textbox

Is there any way? as we can focus the textbox and the datagridview at the same time? in C#

Comment: I am in a process of creating a POS software in the inventory form there is a datagridview if i focus a particular cell another datagridview should popup and i can both type or select the data from the popup datagridview. I have seen this type of software before can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: What has this anything to do with focus ? Please expand the question with details of your intended functionality

Comment: Focus is everything here for example if i am on a 5th row of the popup datagridview (NOTE: currently i am on the datagridview focus) and the first cell value is 'green' i want to search for say 'green apple' i can just type ' apple' and the textbox value got changed how can i type focusing the datagridview and the textbox value got changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already answered your question in last comment. Subscribe on KeyDown/KeyPress...a key event you need, and print character you receive on a TextBox, which will triger event back to filter DataGrid content.

Answer (score 0):

Windows only supports one control in focus at a time. However, nothing will stop you from drawing other controls to look as if they are in focus to get the desired effect you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but giving you some code as an example of that would probably take at least several hours that I don't have right now.  I can try to point you in the right direction if you tell me which part you are having problems with.